# Sustainability of "Finding Nemo" species as pets

Tags: pets

In a restaurant I'm in, there's a fish tank where at least some species are from "Finding Nemo". There's some clownfish, regal teals (Dory), and a couple of other species.

Are clownfish, or regal tangs, or any species from the movie that'd be plausibly found in a fish tank (eg not sharks) inherently unsustainable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Occelaris clowns are easy to breed in captivity and in Australia are regularly advertised as 'tank bred' and not 'wild caught.'

Some species of shrimp are also easy to breed but not necessarily cleaner shrimp as in the movie. I'd suggest that the rest of the fish and invertebrates in the fn tank could only ever be wild caught.

The effect of the aquarium industry on reefs is anyone's guess with compelling arguments for and against.